# Assembly - Replace a word

Tags: assembly, input, replace, cpu-word

So, in this program, I need to input 2 strings. One to select which word to replace (on the default message set in info1) and another for the new word.

That said, when we get to the actual replacement, I get stuck in an infinite loop. Can anyone point me in the right direction? :)

```
#make_COM#    
ORG  100H  

.Data

info1 db 'original message:',13,10,'$'

space db 13,10,'$'

msgorig   db 'a ana e anita em anadia',13,10,'$' 

info2 db 'input the word to be replaced',13,10,'$'
info3 db 'input the replacing word',13,10,'$'

fint  db 60 dup(?)

fsubs  db 60 dup(?)

.Code 

mov ah,9
lea dx, info1
int 21h    

mov ah,9
lea dx, space
int 21h 

mov ah,9
lea dx, msgorig
int 21h

mov ah,9
lea dx, space
int 21h 

mov ah,9
lea dx, info2
int 21h 

mov ah,9
lea dx, space
int 21h 

lea si,fsubs 

subs1:    
    mov ah,1
    int 21h 
    cmp al, 13 
    Jz subs2

    mov [si], al
    inc si
    jmp subs1

subs2:

    mov al, '$'
    mov [si],al
    mov ah,9
    lea dx, space
    int 21h

show1:
    mov ah,9
    lea dx, space
    int 21h


    mov ah,9
    lea dx, info2
    int 21h 

    lea si,fint

 troca1:
    mov ah,1
    int 21h 
    cmp al, 13 
    Jz troca2

    mov [si], al
    inc si
    jmp troca1

troca2:
    mov ah,9
    lea dx, space
    int 21h
    mov al, '$'
    mov [si],al

tcp:
    lea si,msgorig
    mov al,[si]
    lea si,fsubs  ; al e a mensagem origem
    mov bl,[si]   ;(ana) bl e a string que vai ser substituida
    lea si,fint   ;(lumiar) dl e a string que vai substituir
    mov dl,[si]

tcp1:
    cmp al,'$'    ; comp se msg org xegou ao fim
    jz fim
    cmp bl,al    ; comp se ana e ana
    jz tcp2      ; saltar para tcp2 para substituir
    jnz tcp3     ; saltar para tcp3 para inc msg org

tcp2:
    inc dl
    inc al
    cmp al, bl   ;cmp mesg org com ana
    jnz tcp1     ; se ja nao e salta para tras
    inc dl
    inc al
    mov al,dl    ; substitui al[0] por dl[0] 
    jmp tcp2     ; return again!!!\(O_O)/ Praise the sun

tcp3:
    inc al       ; inc a pocisao da msg orig
    jmp tcp1     ; salta para tras para cmp   

fim:   
    mov ah,4CH
    int 21h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem here is that you are mixing pointers and values!
At your *tcp3* label you don't want to increment the character in AL but the **pointer to this character**. Use several address registers like DI, SI, and BX to address memory. (To liberate BX you can use AH where you used BL)

```
tcp:
lea di,msgorig
mov al,[di]
...
tcp3:
inc di
mov al,[di]
jmp tcp1
```

The next code DOES NOT substitute characters!

```
mov al,dl    ; substitui al[0] por dl[0]
```

You need to write DL at a convenient address.

```
mov [di],dl  ;This will substitute
```

The *tcp2* part is very unclear to me because of the forementioned problems. You need to rework it whole.